# Unable to view webpage when url is changed to https in dedicated server

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

i have transered my asp.net website to a dedicated server two days back.earlier it was hosted in a shared hosting.In payment acceptance page rewriting the url using.

```
If Request.IsSecureConnection = False Then  
         HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("http://", "https://"))
End If
```

this was working fine in shared hosting.
but in dedicated server it is showing **'Unable to connect'**

How can i solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have a SSL certificate installed and configured in your new server

Answer (score 0):

The new site hasn't been configured to allow SSL traffic over 443.

You should verify that the SSL certificate has been installed and that the host headers for your site have been configured to route traffic over 443 to your site using the correct cert.

Try following [these steps](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis) outlined in the tutotrial.  You should be able to modify your site's binding to handle the HTTPS requests.

[image]